Solution of system with some oscillations
I have already done the phase portrait of the following system:
$$x'=y,y'=-y-x+x^2$$
and I want to plot it. It should be something like this (so that it must be decreasing with some oscillations


What are the boundary conditions? and if you already have the phase potrate then what else do you need?

@user444 actulaly i want to see the behavoir of x  , for the boundary i have that at time large ,x goes to 0 and in$-\infty$ is 1

You equation may be written simpler as:
x''[t] == -x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^2

To solve, we need 2 initial condition: x[0] and x'[0]. With this:
eq = {x''[t] == -x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == -0.1};
tm = 15;
sol = x /. NDSolve[eq, x, {t, 0, tm}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity][[1]]
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, tm}]



i want also to show the negative x-axis how can i ?

Simply write sol = x /. NDSolve[eq, x, {t, -2, tm}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity][[1]] Plot[sol[t], {t, -2, tm}]

For visualization for some initial conditions:
vp = VectorPlot[{y, -y - x + x^2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}];
fun[a_, b_] := Module[{eq, sol, d},
  eq = {x''[t] == -x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^2, x[0] == a, x'[0] == b};
  sol = x /. NDSolve[eq, x, {t, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity][[1]];
  d[u_] := D[sol[t], t] /. t -> u;
  Column[{Show[vp, ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol[t], d[t]}],
      {t, 0, 10}], ImageSize -> 300, 
     Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[{a, b}]}],
    Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}, 
     ImageSize -> 300]
    }]]
tab = Table[fun[0.25, i], {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.11}];

The Table could changed to Manipulate. The following is exported animated gif:


this code doesnt work

Could you explain what does not work. I used version 14.0. One has to be careful around initial conditions.

the code doesnt visualise

The semicolon at end of last line suppresses output as it is a large number of graphics. As expressed, change Table to to Manipulate or export table as gif which is what I did. Alternatively just run fun[a,b] for whatever initial condition you like. Self evidently, I produced the graphic by running the code and have rechecked. This is version 14.0.

@ubdqn thanks for your answer
